# Mapping a large set of items to a smaller set of position markers

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a set of images ordered in sequence that the user can navigate. Since the images can be of any number, to help navigation, there is a 10  image (fixed number) thumbnail strip in the UI that maps the original set of images (sequence numbers, say Img_1 to Img_569 to to an equally spaced (as much as possible) set Thumb_1 to Thumb_10 (corresponding to the 10 thumbnails). Thumb_1 should correspond to Img_1 and Thumb_10 should correspond to Img_569. What is the best way to do the mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int imgnum = 569;
int thumbmap [10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) thumbmap [i] = imgnum * i / 9;
```

thumbmap [i] is the index of the image for thumbnail i.
i

Answer (score 1):

I would just do a simple mapping unless there was a compelling reason not to

```
int imageCount = 569;
int thumbCount = 10;
float stepSize = (float)imageCount/(float)thumbCount; // use a float to avoid error accumulation

for(int i =0; i < thumbCount; i++)
{
    thumbs[i] = images[(int)(i*stepSize)];
}
```